# Access ListView item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom `ListView` that I'm populating with my `AnswerButton`

This is row layout of listView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.app.Ui.AnswerButton
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/answerRow"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        fbutton:buttonColor="@color/fbutton_color_asbestos"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

List Adapter:

```
public class AnswerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    private List<GameAnswerModel> places = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public AnswerListAdapter(Context ctx){
       this.ctx = ctx;
       mInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void add(GameAnswerModel object) {
        this.places.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.places.size();
    }

    @Override
    public GameAnswerModel getItem(int position) {
        return this.places.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        AnswerHolder answerHolder = null;

        final GameAnswerModel obj = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            answerHolder = new AnswerHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_question_answer,  null);
            answerHolder.answerText = (AnswerButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.answerRow);
            convertView.setTag(answerHolder);
        }

       else
            answerHolder = (AnswerHolder)convertView.getTag();

        answerHolder.answerText.setText(obj.getAnswerText());
        final AnswerHolder finalAnswerHolder = answerHolder;


        return convertView;
    }

    public static class AnswerHolder {
        public AnswerButton answerText;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to access an item in that list using index. But it's not working.

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) answerListAdapter.getView(indexNum, null, parent);

AnswerButton answer = (AnswerButton) parent.getChildAt(0); //get child in linearLay
answer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //for test, not working and not giving error

answerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

How can I access that button in listView **so I can use it's methods**?
(This is for a multiplayer game.)

AnswerButton:

```
public class AnswerButton extends FButton {


    public AnswerButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AnswerButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AnswerButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setCorrectColor(){
        this.setButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fbutton_color_green_sea));
    }
    public void setWrongColor(){
        this.setButtonColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.fbutton_color_pomegranate));
    }
   //..
}
```

Comment: `answerListAdapter` is, well, hmmm, Adapter! ... Adapter creates and bind the view ... `calling answerListAdapter.getView(indexNum, null, parent);` (outside of `AdapterView<?>`) makes no sens at all ... it just creates new row view ...

Comment: Why are you trying to access it like this? is there a purpose for that?

Comment: it seems like he wana hide the button somewhere ... I'm pretty sure that in onClick of the button itself ... so `onClick (View v) => v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` should be ok ... of course after the view is recycled he should "reset" visibility ... [you should watch this mandatory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

Comment: @EE66 I need to change it's color.

Comment: @Selvin, I get it. So how can I access it/them without onClick? Because I onClick is useless for me.

Comment: as @EE66 wrote, write where you wana do this ... also check `AdapterView.getChildAt`

Answer (score 2):

Issue: Change the state of a view inside a row in a ListView from an unrelated event.
I would have change the dataset and then call the adapter.notifyItemChanged(position), if its RecyclerView. if its a ListView then notifyDataChanged(). At the adapter u need to bind the view accordingly.

Comment: But I need to do it without onClick.

Comment: So i didnt understand. You need to change the state of a button in a row of a ListView from some event not related to the view/row itself?

Comment: Yes. This is a multiplayer game. When the opponent user click to answer, current user will see the state of opponent answer in this listView.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have a boolean field **correct** in your **GameAnswerModel** indicating whether this item is the correct one or not.

Then, you could check in the **getView()** if the model's object method **isCorrect()** returns true or false - set the correct background color of your button. And then you should have a method in your adapter where you will set the correct answer:

```
public void setCorrectAnswer(int index) {
    places.get(index).setCorrect();
    notifyDataSetChange();
}
```

That way it will set the correct answer in your places ArrayList and reload the adapter.

Comment: Actually I have that method. This is a multi-player game and I need to access that rows when the **opponent user** clicks.

Comment: Okay, what is your idea? 

You have a list of answers presented to two players. You want to indicate the correct answer by changing it's row color when one of the users clicks on it?

You have 3 possible outcomes:
- Player One clicks on the correct answer - the answer's row is colored in green (for example).
- Player One clicks on the wrong answer - the answer's row is colored in red and the correct one is colored in green.
- Both players clicks on the wrong answers - everyones wrong answer is colored in red and the correct one in green.

Is that so?

Comment: Yes, as you said. So I'm trying to access rows(4 answers) in listview based on index(0-3).

Comment: It is better to change the data - your correct answer object in your ArrayList of answers and then call notifyDataSetChange() in order to refresh the views.

It's not a good practice to get the whole view and manipulate it.

It's possible that I don't get your idea of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Think about "quizup" app. Users can see their answers, this is what I'm trying to do. Thanks for suggestions, I'm working.

Comment: You want to make the two players see their answers until the time is over, correct? 

So I think that what I suggested you above would help you. You just have to call setCorrectAnswer() or change it to setSelectedAnswer() when the user selects one.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to achieve. But first, I need to access them.

Comment: I just looked the "quizup" source code. They are not generating answer rows in runtime like me so it's very easy to manipulate. I guess I'm choosing their way.